# how to generate or create wsdl xsd file with same request more than once

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, xsd

```
<bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
     <bew:mandt>?</bew:mandt>
     <bew:sernr>?</bew:sernr>
     <bew:fzg_kz>?</bew:fzg_kz>
  </bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
```

My requirement is to generate xsd from java as below

```
 <bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
     <bew:mandt>?</bew:mandt>
     <bew:sernr>?</bew:sernr>
     <bew:fzg_kz>?</bew:fzg_kz>
  </bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
 <bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
     <bew:mandt>?</bew:mandt>
     <bew:sernr>?</bew:sernr>
     <bew:fzg_kz>?</bew:fzg_kz>
  </bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
 <bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest>
     <bew:mandt>?</bew:mandt>
     <bew:sernr>?</bew:sernr>
     <bew:fzg_kz>?</bew:fzg_kz>
  </bew:addBew_Data_KomRequest> with max as unbound.
```

I couldn't find any solution.
I am currently using maven spring boot wsdl application as CRUD application to create a interface and dump data to our database from external source.

Comment: What's with the random tags here? What language are you wanting to do this in? You mention java in the question; if so, what does this have to do with SQL Server, and Maven?

Comment: @Larnu, All these tags required since I am working on creating CRUD interface for external data source using java and ms sql as technologies and wsdl (xsd) as type language for other application.

Comment: So what part of the question you are asking requires SQL Server **and** Java **and** maven in the solution for generating the XML? Why would you want to build part of the XML in Java, part in TSsQL, and then the rest as part of a build process in Maven? That's massively over complicating it. Chose a single place to do it, and do it there.

Comment: @Larnu, Idea was to tag these technologies so that people who working on these technologies might already have come across such this scenerio.

Comment: That isn't what tags are for. Tags are to tag the application/language that is relevant to the question you are asking. You wouldn't tag "Windows" just because that's the environment your application is running in.